# Img path issues reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am developing a react app. I am loading datas from a module like that

```
const results = [
{
    'home': 'fbc',
    'home_score': '74',
    'visitor': 'jda',
    'visitor_score': '69',
    'home_logo': 'jda_logo.png'
}]
```

What I am trying to do is loading images from the data (home_logo). But I don't know how to use relative path with React.
I wanted to see what is the path when I load a picture with

```
import jda from './img/jda_logo.png';
```

And I am surprised the path is `static/media/jda_logo.e596d19c.png` Someone can explain to me what is the e596d19c that's been added ?
And is it possible from me to load images with relative path that I am loading from my data ?

Comment: are you using webpack for build? if so, the extra bit is added by file-loader , more ref here : https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-loader

Comment: Yes I am using webpack, and it's for that thank you for the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion react is returning you the reference to the cached/copied media. Usually this is a result of the behaviour of builders/compilers/bundlers such as [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/). Essentially the image is the same but it is copied to a different location, used at runtime.

I believe you would like to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44154939/load-local-images-in-react-js) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644265/correct-path-for-img-on-react-js) as they're handling questions quite close to yours.