# How to give Image src dynamically in react js?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to give image name in src dynamically. I want to set image name dynamically using variable with path. but I am not able to set src correctly. I tried solutions on stackoverflow but nothing is working.

I tried to give path like this

```
<img src={`../img/${img.code}.jpg`}></img>

<img src={'../img/' + img.code + '.jpg'}></img>

<img src={'../img/{img.code}.jpg'}></img>
```

my images are saved in src/img path
if i give path like this

```
<img src={require('../img/nokia.jpg')}/>
```

image is showing

I know this question is asked before but nothing is working for me.
Please help me how can I set image path?

Comment: if you dont want to require the image then you have to put all your images into public folder and then **<img src={`../img/${img.code}.jpg`}></img>** this method will work.

Comment: @Vikas Singh thanks you solved my problem. please add  this as answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63550036/react-webpack-error-runtime-loading-of-image#63550336. It will give some information for loading runtime image

Answer (score 72, accepted):

if you dont want to require the image then you have to put all your images into public folder and then

```
<img src={`../img/${img.code}.jpg`}></img>
```

this method will work.

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/

Comment: Make sure you adjust the path correctly. If you have a folder called `img` that is in the `public` folder then the path would be: 

`<img src={`img/${img.code}.jpg`}></img>`

Answer (score 26):

You can still use require

```
<img src={require(`./img/${img.code}.jpg`)}/>
```

It's not recommended to manually add images to the public folder. See this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44158919/1275105

Comment: require doesn't allow variables. It has to be a string literal.

Comment: @backslashN this does work (at least locally), if needed you can use "./img/"+img.code+".jpg" - React will convert it to the string before importing it.

Comment: I experienced the opposite. If the public folder missing the image there is a small icon that meaning missing the image. But if i use src/assets folder and missing the image then crash the app.

Comment: This didn't work for me using template literals, but it did when I switched to concatenating with the addition operator.  Can anyone explain why?  Tried looking at the string interpolation and template literal docs but couldn't find any clues.

Comment: This does not work for Vite. [This page](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#new-url-url-import-meta-url) has multiple ways to deal with assets, of which the first one is eliminated because in my case, I have to import image dynamically. The third case (using `new URL()`) also does not work, for me.

Answer (score 8):

One pretty simple solution:

// images.js

```
const images = [
  { id: 1, src: './assets/image01.jpg', title: 'foo', description: 'bar' },
  { id: 2, src: './assets/image02.jpg', title: 'foo', description: 'bar' },
  { id: 3, src: './assets/image03.jpg', title: 'foo', description: 'bar' },
  { id: 4, src: './assets/image04.jpg', title: 'foo', description: 'bar' },
  { id: 5, src: './assets/image05.jpg', title: 'foo', description: 'bar' },
  ...etc
];
export default images;
```

You can then import it form another component like this:

```
// MyComponent.js
import images from './images'

//...snip

{ images.map(({id, src, title, description}) => <img key={id} src={src} title={title} alt={description} />)
```

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic require doesn't seems to be clean and also eslint isn't happy with it (not sure why)

Other two approaches if images are stored in public folder :

`const imgNameWithPath = '/fullImageNameWithPath.jpg'`

1. Using env
    `<img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + imgNameWithPath} />`
2. Using location origin:
    `<img src={window.location.origin + imgNameWithPath} />`

Answer (score -1):

If you guys get the path from the database for multiple images and need to use in single tag, you can follow the below method.
step 1 : Please make sure the images are in public folder.
step 2 : Update your path should start from public not from src.
step 3 : Make sure to verify that the path should be using like a variable. If your images path should be using in variable imgPath. You can use your code like var imgPath = '/img/pic.jpeg'
"src={imgPath}"

I hope this will help you..