# How do plug in data inside a url string in React?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

> I'm trying to get some data from my state passed down into this img
>   src url, and I can't seem to figure how to write it. I've tried using back
>   ticks and the dollar sign. I assume because I'm down in the render part
>   of the Component that won't work. Help me Obi-Wan, you're my only
>   hope.

```
<img src={'https://openweathermap.org/img/w/{data.weather.icon}.png'} alt='weather condition' />
```

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54033765/how-to-give-image-src-dynamically-in-react-js

If it will not help you, I suggest you add your component code also for better understanding

Answer (score 1):

Just like with vanilla JS, you have to use a [Template Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and use string interpolation to place your JS within the string (with a `${...}`) like so:

```
<img src={`https://openweathermap.org/img/w/${data.weather.icon}.png`} alt='weather condition' />
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Template Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
<img src={`https://openweathermap.org/img/w/${data.weather.icon}.png`} alt='weather condition' />
```

Comment: I tried that already, it doesn't work. That's what I was referring to when I mentioned the back ticks and the dollar sign. I don't why its not working. Is that the only way to go about it?

Comment: you can still use the old way to template concatenation using `+` operator like `'https://openweathermap.org/img/w/' + data.weather.icon + '.png'`
But i want to understand why that didn't work as it should work. can you share same for what is there in `data.weather.icon`?

Comment: The first thing I tried was the + operator but I was getting errors from VS Code, it didn't like it. I know I was writing it correctly because it was how I inserted data from my state when I did my api call earlier in my code. The information that's in `data.weather.icon` is `"03n"`

Comment: I figured it out. What you wrote did work. I forgot the icon string was in an array. That was my mistake. Thank you!

Comment: @ScottLadd what was that mistake if you don't mind sharing?

Comment: Oh, it was like I said. I forgot that that the information I was trying to get to was in an array so I just needed to add that to the path `data.weather[0].icon`. It hit me when I was looking at the error I was getting from react on the browser that said "Cannot read undefined of .png"