# React webpack error Runtime loading of image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm trying to load image at runtime in my react component.

The images are stored inside src/assets folder

```
var bg=require('../../../assets/plot1.jpg');
return(
<div  style ={ { backgroundImage: "url("+bg+")"} }>  </div>
);
```

This code works and loads the image. however I want to get the image path at runtime. so if i change my code as below

```
 var bg=require(props.bgImg);
```

where the value of `props.bgImg` is `../../../assets/plot1.jpg`. Then i get below error

**Error**

```
    Error: Cannot find module '../../../assets/plot1.jpg'
    webpackEmptyContext

Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push]
D:/data/sdf/webpack/bootstrap:32
  29 |  deferredModules.push.apply(deferredModules, executeModules || []);
  30 | 
  31 |  // run deferred modules when all chunks ready
> 32 |  return checkDeferredModules();
     | ^  33 | };
  34 | function checkDeferredModules() {
  35 |  var result;
```

Will my image be stored in different path after compilation.
How can i provide the path at runtime.

My package.json

```
   "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5"
```

added webpack.config.js

```js
// @remove-on-eject-begin
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */
// @remove-on-eject-end
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const resolve = require('resolve');
const PnpWebpackPlugin = require('pnp-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');
const InlineChunkHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InlineChunkHtmlPlugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const safePostCssParser = require('postcss-safe-parser');
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
const WorkboxWebpackPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
const WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin');
const ModuleScopePlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleScopePlugin');
const getCSSModuleLocalIdent = require('react-dev-utils/getCSSModuleLocalIdent');
const paths = require('./paths');
const modules = require('./modules');
const getClientEnvironment = require('./env');
const ModuleNotFoundPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleNotFoundPlugin');
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin');
const typescriptFormatter = require('react-dev-utils/typescriptFormatter');
// @remove-on-eject-begin
const getCacheIdentifier = require('react-dev-utils/getCacheIdentifier');
// @remove-on-eject-end
const postcssNormalize = require('postcss-normalize');

const appPackageJson = require(paths.appPackageJson);

// Source maps are resource heavy and can cause out of memory issue for large source files.
const shouldUseSourceMap = process.env.GENERATE_SOURCEMAP !== 'false';
// Some apps do not need the benefits of saving a web request, so not inlining the chunk
// makes for a smoother build process.
const shouldInlineRuntimeChunk = process.env.INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK !== 'false';

const isExtendingEslintConfig = process.env.EXTEND_ESLINT === 'true';

const imageInlineSizeLimit = parseInt(
  process.env.IMAGE_INLINE_SIZE_LIMIT || '10000'
);

// Check if TypeScript is setup
const useTypeScript = fs.existsSync(paths.appTsConfig);

// style files regexes
const cssRegex = /\.css$/;
const cssModuleRegex = /\.module\.css$/;
const sassRegex = /\.(scss|sass)$/;
const sassModuleRegex = /\.module\.(scss|sass)$/;

// This is the production and development configuration.
// It is focused on developer experience, fast rebuilds, and a minimal bundle.
module.exports = function(webpackEnv) {
  const isEnvDevelopment = webpackEnv === 'development';
  const isEnvProduction = webpackEnv === 'production';

  // Variable used for enabling profiling in Production
  // passed into alias object. Uses a flag if passed into the build command
  const isEnvProductionProfile =
    isEnvProduction && process.argv.includes('--profile');

  // We will provide `paths.publicUrlOrPath` to our app
  // as %PUBLIC_URL% in `index.html` and `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` in JavaScript.
  // Omit trailing slash as %PUBLIC_URL%/xyz looks better than %PUBLIC_URL%xyz.
  // Get environment variables to inject into our app.
  const env = getClientEnvironment(paths.publicUrlOrPath.slice(0, -1));

  // common function to get style loaders
  const getStyleLoaders = (cssOptions, preProcessor) => {
    const loaders = [
      isEnvDevelopment && require.resolve('style-loader'),
      isEnvProduction && {
        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        // css is located in `static/css`, use '../../' to locate index.html folder
        // in production `paths.publicUrlOrPath` can be a relative path
        options: paths.publicUrlOrPath.startsWith('.')
          ? { publicPath: '../../' }
          : {},
      },
      {
        loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
        options: cssOptions,
      },
      {
        // Options for PostCSS as we reference these options twice
        // Adds vendor prefixing based on your specified browser support in
        // package.json
        loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
        options: {
          // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
          // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2677
          ident: 'postcss',
          plugins: () => [
            require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
            require('postcss-preset-env')({
              autoprefixer: {
                flexbox: 'no-2009',
              },
              stage: 3,
            }),
            // Adds PostCSS Normalize as the reset css with default options,
            // so that it honors browserslist config in package.json
            // which in turn let's users customize the target behavior as per their needs.
            postcssNormalize(),
          ],
          sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
        },
      },
    ].filter(Boolean);
    if (preProcessor) {
      loaders.push(
        {
          loader: require.resolve('resolve-url-loader'),
          options: {
            sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
          },
        },
        {
          loader: require.resolve(preProcessor),
          options: {
            sourceMap: true,
          },
        }
      );
    }
    return loaders;
  };

  return {
    mode: isEnvProduction ? 'production' : isEnvDevelopment && 'development',
    // Stop compilation early in production
    bail: isEnvProduction,
    devtool: isEnvProduction
      ? shouldUseSourceMap
        ? 'source-map'
        : false
      : isEnvDevelopment && 'cheap-module-source-map',
    // These are the "entry points" to our application.
    // This means they will be the "root" imports that are included in JS bundle.
    entry: [
      
      isEnvDevelopment &&
        require.resolve('react-dev-utils/webpackHotDevClient'),
      // Finally, this is your app's code:
      paths.appIndexJs,
      // We include the app code last so that if there is a runtime error during
      // initialization, it doesn't blow up the WebpackDevServer client, and
      // changing JS code would still trigger a refresh.
    ].filter(Boolean),
    output: {
      // The build folder.
      path: isEnvProduction ? paths.appBuild : undefined,
      // Add /* filename */ comments to generated require()s in the output.
      pathinfo: isEnvDevelopment,
      // There will be one main bundle, and one file per asynchronous chunk.
      // In development, it does not produce real files.
      filename: isEnvProduction
        ? 'static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].js'
        : isEnvDevelopment && 'static/js/bundle.js',
      // TODO: remove this when upgrading to webpack 5
      futureEmitAssets: true,
      // There are also additional JS chunk files if you use code splitting.
      chunkFilename: isEnvProduction
        ? 'static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.js'
        : isEnvDevelopment && 'static/js/[name].chunk.js',
      // webpack uses `publicPath` to determine where the app is being served from.
      // It requires a trailing slash, or the file assets will get an incorrect path.
      // We inferred the "public path" (such as / or /my-project) from homepage.
      publicPath: paths.publicUrlOrPath,
      // Point sourcemap entries to original disk location (format as URL on Windows)
      devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: isEnvProduction
        ? info =>
            path
              .relative(paths.appSrc, info.absoluteResourcePath)
              .replace(/\\/g, '/')
        : isEnvDevelopment &&
          (info => path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, '/')),
      // Prevents conflicts when multiple webpack runtimes (from different apps)
      // are used on the same page.
      jsonpFunction: `webpackJsonp${appPackageJson.name}`,
      // this defaults to 'window', but by setting it to 'this' then
      // module chunks which are built will work in web workers as well.
      globalObject: 'this',
    },
    optimization: {
      minimize: isEnvProduction,
      minimizer: [
        // This is only used in production mode
        new TerserPlugin({
          terserOptions: {
            parse: {
              // We want terser to parse ecma 8 code. However, we don't want it
              // to apply any minification steps that turns valid ecma 5 code
              // into invalid ecma 5 code. This is why the 'compress' and 'output'
              // sections only apply transformations that are ecma 5 safe
              // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/4234
              ecma: 8,
            },
            compress: {
              ecma: 5,
              warnings: false,

              comparisons: false,

              inline: 2,
            },
            mangle: {
              safari10: true,
            },
            // Added for profiling in devtools
            keep_classnames: isEnvProductionProfile,
            keep_fnames: isEnvProductionProfile,
            output: {
              ecma: 5,
              comments: false,
              // Turned on because emoji and regex is not minified properly using default
              // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2488
              ascii_only: true,
            },
          },
          sourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
        }),
        // This is only used in production mode
        new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({
          cssProcessorOptions: {
            parser: safePostCssParser,
            map: shouldUseSourceMap
              ? {
                  // `inline: false` forces the sourcemap to be output into a
                  // separate file
                  inline: false,
                  // `annotation: true` appends the sourceMappingURL to the end of
                  // the css file, helping the browser find the sourcemap
                  annotation: true,
                }
              : false,
          },
          cssProcessorPluginOptions: {
            preset: ['default', { minifyFontValues: { removeQuotes: false } }],
          },
        }),
      ],

      splitChunks: {
        chunks: 'all',
        name: false,
      },
      // Keep the runtime chunk separated to enable long term caching
      // https://twitter.com/wSokra/status/969679223278505985
      // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5358
      runtimeChunk: {
        name: entrypoint => `runtime-${entrypoint.name}`,
      },
    },
    resolve: {

      modules: ['node_modules', paths.appNodeModules].concat(
        modules.additionalModulePaths || []
      ),

      extensions: paths.moduleFileExtensions
        .map(ext => `.${ext}`)
        .filter(ext => useTypeScript || !ext.includes('ts')),
      alias: {
        // Support React Native Web
        // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
        'react-native': 'react-native-web',
        // Allows for better profiling with ReactDevTools
        ...(isEnvProductionProfile && {
          'react-dom$': 'react-dom/profiling',
          'scheduler/tracing': 'scheduler/tracing-profiling',
        }),
        ...(modules.webpackAliases || {}),
      },
      plugins: [
        // Adds support for installing with Plug'n'Play, leading to faster installs and adding
        // guards against forgotten dependencies and such.
        PnpWebpackPlugin,
 
        new ModuleScopePlugin(paths.appSrc, [paths.appPackageJson]),
      ],
    },
    resolveLoader: {
      plugins: [
        // Also related to Plug'n'Play, but this time it tells webpack to load its loaders
        // from the current package.
        PnpWebpackPlugin.moduleLoader(module),
      ],
    },
    module: {
      strictExportPresence: true,
      rules: [
        // Disable require.ensure as it's not a standard language feature.
        { parser: { requireEnsure: false } },

        // First, run the linter.
        // It's important to do this before Babel processes the JS.
        {
          test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
          enforce: 'pre',
          use: [
            {
              options: {
                cache: true,
                formatter: require.resolve('react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter'),
                eslintPath: require.resolve('eslint'),
                resolvePluginsRelativeTo: __dirname,
                // @remove-on-eject-begin
                ignore: isExtendingEslintConfig,
                baseConfig: isExtendingEslintConfig
                  ? undefined
                  : {
                      extends: [require.resolve('eslint-config-react-app')],
                    },
                useEslintrc: isExtendingEslintConfig,
                // @remove-on-eject-end
              },
              loader: require.resolve('eslint-loader'),
            },
          ],
          include: paths.appSrc,
        },
        {

          oneOf: [
          
            {
              test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
              loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
              options: {
                limit: imageInlineSizeLimit,
                name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
              },
            },
            // Process application JS with Babel.
            // The preset includes JSX, Flow, TypeScript, and some ESnext features.
            {
              test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
              include: paths.appSrc,
              loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
              options: {
                customize: require.resolve(
                  'babel-preset-react-app/webpack-overrides'
                ),
                // @remove-on-eject-begin
                babelrc: false,
                configFile: false,
                presets: [require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app')],
                // Make sure we have a unique cache identifier, erring on the
                // side of caution.
                // We remove this when the user ejects because the default
                // is sane and uses Babel options. Instead of options, we use
                // the react-scripts and babel-preset-react-app versions.
                cacheIdentifier: getCacheIdentifier(
                  isEnvProduction
                    ? 'production'
                    : isEnvDevelopment && 'development',
                  [
                    'babel-plugin-named-asset-import',
                    'babel-preset-react-app',
                    'react-dev-utils',
                    'react-scripts',
                  ]
                ),
                // @remove-on-eject-end
                plugins: [
                  [
                    require.resolve('babel-plugin-named-asset-import'),
                    {
                      loaderMap: {
                        svg: {
                          ReactComponent:
                            '@svgr/webpack?-svgo,+titleProp,+ref![path]',
                        },
                      },
                    },
                  ],
                ],
                // This is a feature of `babel-loader` for webpack (not Babel itself).
                // It enables caching results in ./node_modules/.cache/babel-loader/
                // directory for faster rebuilds.
                cacheDirectory: true,
                // See #6846 for context on why cacheCompression is disabled
                cacheCompression: false,
                compact: isEnvProduction,
              },
            },
            // Process any JS outside of the app with Babel.
            // Unlike the application JS, we only compile the standard ES features.
            {
              test: /\.(js|mjs)$/,
              exclude: /@babel(?:\/|\\{1,2})runtime/,
              loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
              options: {
                babelrc: false,
                configFile: false,
                compact: false,
                presets: [
                  [
                    require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app/dependencies'),
                    { helpers: true },
                  ],
                ],
                cacheDirectory: true,
                // See #6846 for context on why cacheCompression is disabled
                cacheCompression: false,
                // @remove-on-eject-begin
                cacheIdentifier: getCacheIdentifier(
                  isEnvProduction
                    ? 'production'
                    : isEnvDevelopment && 'development',
                  [
                    'babel-plugin-named-asset-import',
                    'babel-preset-react-app',
                    'react-dev-utils',
                    'react-scripts',
                  ]
                ),
        
                sourceMaps: shouldUseSourceMap,
                inputSourceMap: shouldUseSourceMap,
              },
            },
     
            {
              test: cssRegex,
              exclude: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
              }),

              sideEffects: true,
            },
            // Adds support for CSS Modules (https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)
            // using the extension .module.css
            {
              test: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                modules: {
                  getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
                },
              }),
            },
            // Opt-in support for SASS (using .scss or .sass extensions).
            // By default we support SASS Modules with the
            // extensions .module.scss or .module.sass
            {
              test: sassRegex,
              exclude: sassModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders(
                {
                  importLoaders: 3,
                  sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                },
                'sass-loader'
              ),
           
              sideEffects: true,
            },
            // Adds support for CSS Modules, but using SASS
            // using the extension .module.scss or .module.sass
            {
              test: sassModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders(
                {
                  importLoaders: 3,
                  sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
                  modules: {
                    getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
                  },
                },
                'sass-loader'
              ),
            },
           
            {
              loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
              // Exclude `js` files to keep "css" loader working as it injects
              // its runtime that would otherwise be processed through "file" loader.
              // Also exclude `html` and `json` extensions so they get processed
              // by webpacks internal loaders.
              exclude: [/\.(js|mjs|jsx|ts|tsx)$/, /\.html$/, /\.json$/],
              options: {
                name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
              },
            },
            // ** STOP ** Are you adding a new loader?
            // Make sure to add the new loader(s) before the "file" loader.
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      // Generates an `index.html` file with the <script> injected.
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin(
        Object.assign(
          {},
          {
            inject: true,
            template: paths.appHtml,
          },
          isEnvProduction
            ? {
                minify: {
                  removeComments: true,
                  collapseWhitespace: true,
                  removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                  useShortDoctype: true,
                  removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                  removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                  keepClosingSlash: true,
                  minifyJS: true,
                  minifyCSS: true,
                  minifyURLs: true,
                },
              }
            : undefined
        )
      ),
      // Inlines the webpack runtime script. This script is too small to warrant
      // a network request.
      // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5358
      isEnvProduction &&
        shouldInlineRuntimeChunk &&
        new InlineChunkHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, [/runtime-.+[.]js/]),

      new InterpolateHtmlPlugin(HtmlWebpackPlugin, env.raw),
      // This gives some necessary context to module not found errors, such as
      // the requesting resource.
      new ModuleNotFoundPlugin(paths.appPath),
      
      new webpack.DefinePlugin(env.stringified),
      // This is necessary to emit hot updates (currently CSS only):
      isEnvDevelopment && new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      
      isEnvDevelopment && new CaseSensitivePathsPlugin(),
      
      isEnvDevelopment &&
        new WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin(paths.appNodeModules),
      isEnvProduction &&
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
          // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
          // both options are optional
          filename: 'static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].css',
          chunkFilename: 'static/css/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.css',
        }),
      // Generate an asset manifest file with the following content:
      // - "files" key: Mapping of all asset filenames to their corresponding
      //   output file so that tools can pick it up without having to parse
      //   `index.html`
      // - "entrypoints" key: Array of files which are included in `index.html`,
      //   can be used to reconstruct the HTML if necessary
      new ManifestPlugin({
        fileName: 'asset-manifest.json',
        publicPath: paths.publicUrlOrPath,
        generate: (seed, files, entrypoints) => {
          const manifestFiles = files.reduce((manifest, file) => {
            manifest[file.name] = file.path;
            return manifest;
          }, seed);
          const entrypointFiles = entrypoints.main.filter(
            fileName => !fileName.endsWith('.map')
          );

          return {
            files: manifestFiles,
            entrypoints: entrypointFiles,
          };
        },
      }),

      new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
      // Generate a service worker script that will precache, and keep up to date,
      // the HTML & assets that are part of the webpack build.
      isEnvProduction &&
        new WorkboxWebpackPlugin.GenerateSW({
          clientsClaim: true,
          exclude: [/\.map$/, /asset-manifest\.json$/],
          importWorkboxFrom: 'cdn',
          navigateFallback: paths.publicUrlOrPath + 'index.html',
          navigateFallbackBlacklist: [
            // Exclude URLs starting with /_, as they're likely an API call
            new RegExp('^/_'),
            // Exclude any URLs whose last part seems to be a file extension
            // as they're likely a resource and not a SPA route.
            // URLs containing a "?" character won't be blacklisted as they're likely
            // a route with query params (e.g. auth callbacks).
            new RegExp('/[^/?]+\\.[^/]+$'),
          ],
        }),
      // TypeScript type checking
      useTypeScript &&
        new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
          typescript: resolve.sync('typescript', {
            basedir: paths.appNodeModules,
          }),
          async: isEnvDevelopment,
          useTypescriptIncrementalApi: true,
          checkSyntacticErrors: true,
          resolveModuleNameModule: process.versions.pnp
            ? `${__dirname}/pnpTs.js`
            : undefined,
          resolveTypeReferenceDirectiveModule: process.versions.pnp
            ? `${__dirname}/pnpTs.js`
            : undefined,
          tsconfig: paths.appTsConfig,
          reportFiles: [
            '**',
            '!**/__tests__/**',
            '!**/?(*.)(spec|test).*',
            '!**/src/setupProxy.*',
            '!**/src/setupTests.*',
          ],
          silent: true,
          // The formatter is invoked directly in WebpackDevServerUtils during development
          formatter: isEnvProduction ? typescriptFormatter : undefined,
        }),
    ].filter(Boolean),
    
    node: {
      module: 'empty',
      dgram: 'empty',
      dns: 'mock',
      fs: 'empty',
      http2: 'empty',
      net: 'empty',
      tls: 'empty',
      child_process: 'empty',
    },
    // Turn off performance processing because we utilize
    // our own hints via the FileSizeReporter
    performance: false,
  };
};
```

Comment: What webpack loader are you using for images? `file-loader` should return a url for the image, which then can be used in runtime.

Comment: Can you please give some more details of finding the image url.  and how can i find webpack loader

Comment: The syntax is the same, but the webpack config is different. Can you post your webpack config?

Comment: added webpackDevServer.config.js

Comment: Is this the config from `create-react-app`? This one doesn't have all the config. There should be another one, probably `config/webpack.config.js`.

Comment: Never mind, I spoke too soon. I think I know what's going on. Let me put it in an answer.

Comment: Thank you, added webpack.config.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're loading the image path dynamically, but in runtime and depending on your webpack config, your assets' paths in the bundle can be different from what's in your code.

Here's the default `url-loader` config in webpack for apps created by `create-react-app`:

```
{
    test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
    loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
    options: {
        name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
    },
},
```

As you can see, files matching `test` will end up in `static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]`. So your background image will be saved as `static/media/plot1.<some-hash>.jpg`, which is different from the path you're passing to `require` via `props`, i.e. `../../../assets/plot1.jpg`.

In the first case (`var bg=require('../../../assets/plot1.jpg')`), webpack sees the path, discovers the image, transforms its path, and assings the transformed path to `bg`. In the second case, the value of `props.bg` is unknown at compile time, so webpack doesn't handle it, which your image might not end up in the assets, or if it's there, it's path is not known to your runtime code. The main point is your code shouldn't rely on values that will be modified by bundlers like webpack during the transpile process.

You can put your image paths in an object that is processed by webpack, and then refer to the keys of that object to get the correct image. Here's an example:

Put this some where outside of your components, maybe in a config file or your entry point, wherever that makes the most sense:

```
const IMAGES = {
    bg1: require('<path-to-bg1>'),
    bg2: require('<path-to-bg2>'),
    ...
}
```

And then in the component:

```
const App = (props) => {
    return <div style={{backgroundImage: "url(" + IMAGES[props.bgImg] + ")"}}>...</div>
}
```

Needless to say, you need to update your props to pass a key from `IMAGES`, instead of image paths.

Comment: +1 Thanks Kaveh. This works.if I can understand how webpack places the file after compilation and if i can refer them directly, then that will be more helpful

Comment: @upog I added more explanation to the beginning of the answer. Let me know if it doesn't make sense! :)

Comment: yeah when i debug in developer console i found `/static/media/plot1.838f8b53.jpg` and i dont know how to map and posted the question. Thanks for your explanation

Comment: just to add some information, in `css/scss` if you try to load the image then also it will work fine `background-image: url(../../../assets/plot1.jpg);`

Comment: i think i can remove `.[hash:8]` in wepack and can use `/static/media/` as base path for my image . but not sure of the impact

Comment: The main use of hash, as far as I know, is to avoid issues around caching. Depending on your server config, especially in production, you might end up with old cached assets being served, at least temporarily. Using hash in names is one solution for that. You can see more in webpack docs: https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/