# Not able to display images in <img> tag in Reactjs when i have images in Array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-fullstack

**I am unable to display images in img tag in Reactjs**

```
<ul className="products">
      {products.map((product) => (
        <li key={product._id}>
          <div className="product">
            <Link to={"/product/" + product._id}>
              <img className="product-image" src={product.image} alt="product" />
            </Link>
            <div className="product-name">
              <Link to={"/product/" + product._id}>{product.name}</Link>
            </div>
            <div className="product-brand">{product.brand}</div>
            <div className="product-price">${product.price}</div>
            <div className="product-rating">
              {product.rating} Stars ({product.numReviews} Reviews)
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
```

**Every other data like product.name, product.price etc is getting displayed but problem lies with product.image .**

[image: object image]

**The above pic shows my products array.**

[image: Web page view]

**The above pic shows each component the page**

Comment: Where are your images? (For the approach you're using they should be in `public`)

Comment: I have my images in the same folder in which i have my js file @nthnchu

Comment: @nthnchu if I write code `import Img from './d1.jpg' ` and write `src={Img}` its working.

Comment: That's because setting the src doesn't automatically import them.

Comment: @nthnchu thanks man it worked for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to give Image src dynamically in react js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54033765/how-to-give-image-src-dynamically-in-react-js)

Comment: @nthnchu this is working for the code that i shared to you. But for another code in the same folder this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

These issue appears since React is using webpack as bundler by default. When using assets with the bundler you should provide the image path with `require('...')` or directly import the asset as a module with `import`

In your case `<img className="product-image" src={product.image} alt="product" />`
should be changed to
`<img className="product-image" src={require(product.image)} alt="product" />` or you should restructure your array of objects so that the product.image is a valid path.

I would suggest changing the place where the images are stored to a separate asset folder for a clearer structure instead of referring to them from the root folder