# I need to take an image in React

Tags: reactjs

How can i take an images into React-component?
My image is in `srs/images.`
I try to take it by:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async() => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/user", {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("access_token")}`,
        },
      });

      const {
        firstName,
        lastName,
        avatar
      } = response.data;
      setFirstName(firstName);
      setLastName(lastName);
      setAvatar(avatar);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching user data:", error);
    }
  };

  fetchData();
}, []);
```

my avatar looks like `../images/first_image.png` and than i can't view it in

```
<img src={avatar}
    alt={"Avatar"}
    style={{marginLeft: "5%", width: "4vh"}}/>
```

in my postgres sql the image is like the path:
`../images/four_image.png`

Comment: show us how you import your image

Comment: sorry, what did you want?

Comment: your img seems fine and there's no problem on what you posted. So it might be a problem on how you import your image.

Comment: ow, I just noticed that the `avatar` is a state instead of an import. Nvm

Comment: This might be similar to your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54033765/how-to-give-image-src-dynamically-in-react-js

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src={require(avatar)}
alt={"Avatar"}
style={{marginLeft: "5%", width: "4vh"}}/>
```

Comment: it aslo doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

If the image file is in src/images I think the url needs to be images/first_image.png  (you need to ditch the '..' at the beginning. If all avatar images are stored in this folder, it might be best to store just the filename in the database and have the img src be the filename + a baseUrl:

```
<img src={baseUrl + avatarFilename}
    alt={"Avatar"}
    style={{marginLeft: "5%", width: "4vh"}}/>
```

where

```
const baseUrl = 'images/'
```

Comment: it doesn't work