# How to show image from json file in local host?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

How can I show images from json file in localhost in React Application?
 I'm tryig this below one but it is not working.

json file:

```
{
  "img":"images/img-filename.png"
}
```

image is located at src/images/img-filename.png

In React app, image path is displaying: images/img-filename.png

Comment: you need a file loader,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load local images in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44154939/load-local-images-in-react-js) as  @PPetkov mentions

Answer (score 0):

Images from `src` folder can be displayed in React component by:-

```
<img height="32" src="../images/img-filename.png" />
```

`../` is to go one folder out. I hope it helps.

Comment: I did that, still not showing... file path is coming from .json file. Path is displaying as mentioned in .json but image is still not displaying

Comment: @Ali when you render img object, also add  `../` in src

Comment: json path: 

{
 "img" : "../images/img-filename.png"
 }

React file:

 <img src={data.img} .../>

Comment: It is showing images, after I moved the images folder to the public folder.