# Material UI : How to use my own image in avatar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, avatar

I want to use an image in the avatar. But I am not able to get the desired result.

This is my project structure.

projectname -> packages -> portal -> public -> favicon-16x16.png

```
      <Avatar
        src="/public/favicon-16x16.png"
        className={classes.avatar}
      />
```

```
         <Avatar
           src="packages/portal/public/favicon-16x16.png"   
           className={classes.avatar}  
         />
```

I have tried the above two ways. But not load to get the image. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to have brackets around props, even when they're strings. You also aren't showing the code of how you're trying to use it. Also, we can't see if you're using local images correctly. Check this answer about importing local images https://stackoverflow.com/a/44158919/10140836 . You need to provide more info in your post.

Comment: This the correct way :

```<Avatar
            src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/apple-touch-icon.png`}
            className={classes.avatar}
            style={{ borderRadius: 0 }}
          />```

Thank you @RobB

Comment: @RobB you absolutely do *not* need to use brackets with strings in JSX. Simply using quotation marks is sufficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This the correct way :

```
<Avatar src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/apple-touch-icon.png`} className={classes.avatar} style={{ borderRadius: 0 }} />
```

Thank you @RobB