# React - local image won't load?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

I am attempting to load a local image in React js. Following [this answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582405/react-wont-load-local-images) this is how I've attempted this -

```
<img src={require('../public/images/icon.png').default} />
```

Where the image is icon.png located in my public folder and I'm writing this in the `export default function Home() { return (` portion of my index.js. This is how the image renders:

[image]

I have deployed this to Vercel as well as tested locally, so I do not think this is a server issue. I've tried the import method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44154939/load-local-images-in-react-js) as well.

What is wrong here and how can I load a local image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment I can propose you two options.

1. Import your image as a component.
   Just place this line of code in the head of your file:
   `import {ReactComponent as COMPONENT_NAME} from PATH`
   And place this COMPONENT_NAME in your other components. You can apply stying to it, props and etc.
2. Import your image path.
   `import IMAGE_PATH from PATH`
   And in your component:
   `<img src={IMAGE_PATH} {...options} />`

Comment: Tried both, still getting a 404 in the console though I know I am searching at the right path bc if I change it the pages crashes (Im using Next and Vercel)

Comment: Did you push your code to GitHub or BitBucket and etc., so I can watch it?

Comment: Nvm first option worked thanks!