# How to preload image in a React JS component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preload

I'm currently rendering a child component when a `signInError` occurs. The `signInError` is stored in the parent component and if it's not null, it renders the `<SignInError/>` component, as per the code below:

**ParentComponent.js**

```
  // Some code...

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <SignInForm
          doSignIn={this.doSignIn}
          resetSignInError={this.resetSignInError}
          signInError={this.state.signInError}
        />
        {this.state.signInError && <SignInError/>}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

So far, so good, here's the child component `SignInError.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import RoundImage from '../../../UI/Common/RoundImage';
import Newman from '../../../../assets/newman-min.png';

class SignInError extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

    componentDidMount(){
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = Newman;
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
      <div>
        <RoundImage src={img.src}/> // <--- img is undefined here!!!
      </div>
      <div>
        Hello... Newman!
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SignInError;
```

**RoundImage.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const RoundImage = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={props.src}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default RoundImage;
```

[How to preload images in React.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42615556/how-to-preload-images-in-react-js)

This question's answer (link above) here on Stack Over flow tells me to create the `img` object inside the `componentDidMount()` method to force the browser to load it. And so I did, as you can see from the code above. But now, when I try to pass it as a prop to my grand-child component inside my `render` method, I can't access the `img`, because it was defined inside of another method.

What's the best way around this? I just need the image to be loaded and to be displayed together with the error message. Otherwise the error message will show before the image, if your browser hasn't cached it yet. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is "RoundImage"?

Comment: If RoundImage is expecting a path, why not just use: `<RoundImage src={Newman}/>`?

Comment: I've just edited to add the RoundImage.js code. Thanks.

Comment: @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane I tried that. It works, but it doesn't preload my image. "Hello Newman!" shows before the image. And then, once the browser downloads it, it loads...

Comment: If you want to pre-load it, you need to create the new Image() higher up in your app. By the time the component loads it still doesn't have the image. You don't need to reference this image, you just want to force the browser to fetch it. When you use it in your component, it will already be cached.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Image download happens in the browser. Rendering to the DOM also happens in the browser.

By *preloading*, do you mean that you want that the component renders only when the image is ready?

If so, you could do something like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const img = new Image();
  img.onload = () => {
    // when it finishes loading, update the component state
    this.setState({ imageIsReady: true });
  }
  img.src = Newman; // by setting an src, you trigger browser download

}

render() {
  const { imageIsReady } = this.state;

  if (!imageIsReady) {
    return <div>Loading image...</div>; // or just return null if you want nothing to be rendered.
  } else {
    return <img src={Newman} /> // along with your error message here
  }
}
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Just changed your answer's `this.state({ imageIsReady: true });` to `this.setState(...)` and it works just like I intended it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ah yes, thanks for the correction. I have fixed the typo in my answer.

Comment: `img.src` should be placed after `img.onload`. Otherwise, you're risking `onload` not firing in case the image is cached in browser.

Answer (score 11):

A bit of a different approach, but if you have the image source in advance, you can add the image source to the main html file as a link ref with preload option. The browser will preload the image (with relatively low priority) and at the time your app will load the image, it should be cached in the browser memory.

```
<head>
..
..
<link rel="preload" href="<your_image_source_here>" as="image">
...
</head>
```

In this approach, we separate the preloading process from the code. It is more relevant when you have the image source in advance (and not dynamically) and when you don't need to cache a large amount of images (will be a bit messy to add a large list of links in the html head, although possible)

you can learn more about link preloading here: [Preloading content with rel="preload"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really need it handled inside the component, though.

Comment: I'm already importing it in `import Newman from '../../../../assets/newman-min.png';` Wound `require` make any difference?

Comment: No, its equivalent actually (:

Answer (score 0):

In my case I start with an initial src attribute for my images and wanted to delay changing them *after* the image has been loaded by the browser, so I wrote the following hook in Typescript:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const useImageLoader = (initialSrc: string, currentSrc: string) => {
  const [imageSrc, _setImageSrc] = useState(initialSrc);

  useEffect(() => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => {
      _setImageSrc(currentSrc);
    };
    img.src = currentSrc;
  }, [currentSrc]);

  return [imageSrc];
};
```

Comment: can you post an example of your proposed solution?