# Background Image flickering when change - react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, background-image, inline-styles

I have been rewriting my website ondeband.com - it is currently a wordpress website and I am about a month into writing it in react.

I am not going to change the home page too much - it has a background image that changes every couple seconds. You can see it in my link above.

Problem is...on my new react version of the website - it flickers between each image change - speically when I pushed it to heroku. It works 99% of time on my local dev server.

I have a feeling it is due to the 'preloading' of the images? Maybe you can point me in the right direction - Here is my code for the home page of my app.

The div with the className of 'homePage' is where the bg image is loaded into the inline styles. The variable bgImage is stored in state. I use the useEffect hook to start the function, 'bgTransition', that changes each image randomly.

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import NavBarA from "./components/NavBarA";
import { Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import BookABand2 from "./components/Profile/BookABand2";
import LiveProfile from './components/BookABand/LiveProfile'
import Account from './components/Account/Account'
import history from "./uitls/history";
import PrivateRoute from "./components/PrivateRoute";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import AqgSetup3 from "./components/AqgSetup3";
import './App.css';
import { useAuth0 } from './react-auth0-spa'
import Banjo from './BackgroundImgs/Banjo.jpg'
import Hands from './BackgroundImgs/Hands.jpg'
import Mic from './BackgroundImgs/Mic.jpg'
import Sax from './BackgroundImgs/Sax.jpg'
import { Button } from 'reactstrap'

function App() {
  const { user } = useAuth0()
  const [bgImgArray] = useState([Banjo, Hands, Mic, Sax])
  const [ bgImg, setBgImg ] = useState(Banjo)
  const { loginWithRedirect, isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();

  useEffect(() => {
    bgTransition()
  }, [] )

  const bgTransition = () => {
    let newNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)
    setBgImg(bgImgArray[newNum])
    setTimeout(() => {
      bgTransition()
    }, 5000)
  }

  if(!bgImgArray){
    return <div>loading...</div>
  }

  return (
    <div className="App h-100" style={{
      paddingTop: user ? '85px' : '0px'
    }}>
      <Router history={history}>
        <header>
          <NavBarA color={ user ? 'light' : ''} className={user ? 'navbar text-dark fixed-top shadow-lg' : "navbar text-light fixed-top"}/>
        </header>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact >
            <div className='homePage h-100' style={{
              display: !isAuthenticated ? 'block' : 'none',
              backgroundImage: `url(${bgImg})`,
              backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
              backgroundSize: 'cover',
              webkitTransition: 'background-image 1s ease-in-out',
              transition: 'background-image 1s ease-in-out',
            }}>
              <div className='h-100 w-100 position-absolute'style={{
                background: 'linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) )',
                zIndex: '10'
              }}/>
              <div className="d-flex flex-column w-100 h-100 align-items-center justify-content-center position-relative" style={{zIndex: '100'}}>
              <h1 className='text-light'>On Demand</h1>
                <h1 className='text-light'>On DeBand</h1>
                <h6 className='text-light'>Find, Support, and Book Local Bands</h6>
                <div className='d-flex flex-row'>
                  <Button outline color='light' size='lg' className='mx-2 my-2' onClick={() => {loginWithRedirect()}}>Find Bands</Button>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div>

              </div>

            </div>

            <div style={{
              display: user ? 'block' : 'none',
            }}>
              <BookABand2 />
            </div>
          </Route>
          <PrivateRoute path="/BookABand2" component={BookABand2} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/AqgSetup3/:id" component={AqgSetup3} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/band/:id" component={LiveProfile} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/account" component={Account} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with just html, with only small tweaks to your React code.

To download the image earlier you can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54096241). The only problem is, that you don't know the url of the image, because it's randomized once you build the website.

To mitigate this, move your images out of the `src` folder to the `public` folder. I assume you would use `/public/images/` to store them. Here is the modified code:

**index.html**

```
<head>
..
..
<link rel="preload" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/images/Banjo.jpg" as="image">
<link rel="preload" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/images/Hands.jpg" as="image">
<link rel="preload" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/images/Mic.jpg" as="image">
<link rel="preload" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/images/Sax.jpg" as="image">
...
</head>
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import NavBarA from "./components/NavBarA";
import { Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import BookABand2 from "./components/Profile/BookABand2";
import LiveProfile from './components/BookABand/LiveProfile'
import Account from './components/Account/Account'
import history from "./uitls/history";
import PrivateRoute from "./components/PrivateRoute";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import AqgSetup3 from "./components/AqgSetup3";
import './App.css';
import { useAuth0 } from './react-auth0-spa'
import { Button } from 'reactstrap'

function App() {
  const [bgImgArray] = useState(['Banjo.jpg', 'Hands.jpg', 'Mic.jpg', 'Sax.jpg'])
  ...
  return (
    <div className="App h-100" style={{
      paddingTop: user ? '85px' : '0px'
    }}>
      <Router history={history}>
        ...
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact >
            <div className='homePage h-100' style={{
              display: !isAuthenticated ? 'block' : 'none',
              backgroundImage: `url(/public/images/${bgImg})`,
              backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
              backgroundSize: 'cover',
              webkitTransition: 'background-image 1s ease-in-out',
              transition: 'background-image 1s ease-in-out',
            }}>
              ...
            </div>
          </Route>
          ...
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much! Works much better now - https://ondeband.herokuapp.com/ -

Comment: Hey Adam - Do you know if its possible to sort an array of react componenets? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61755267/can-you-sort-an-array-of-react-components-accessing-info-of-react-componenet