# Using a default image on load of the page, then overwrites it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

I have a page which contains several images. When the page loads it provides a default image for each IMG:

```
import default from './pics/default.jpg';

<img src={default} alt="#"/>
```

What I want is something like this:

```
<img src1={default} src2="img url" alt="#"/>
```

Where src2 overwrites src1 when it is loaded.

**Edit:**
The first image (src1) comes as the page loads while the second (src2) is requested trough the internet. *Example*: https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/17/10/52/wind-farm-1747331__340.jpg

Comment: Are the images coming from a reducer or an api request?

Comment: Set the source using a state value which will to re-render it when it is done via set state.

Comment: How should I do that @basic

Comment: You can also checkout [react-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image). It seems to do what you want and has 0 dependencies. Here's the [direct link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image#show-a-spinner-or-other-element-before-the-image-is-loaded) to the documentation to do what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to preload images in React.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42615556/how-to-preload-images-in-react-js)

Comment: React-image does not work. :((

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the `onLoad` event on your `<img>` element. You can give it a `display: none` style until it finishes loading.

```js
class ImageRoll extends React.Component {
  state = {loaded: false};
  
  showImage = () => {
    this.setState({loaded: true});
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <img src="/path-to-initial" style={ this.state.loaded ? {display: "none"} : {}} />
        <img src="/path-to-seocndary" onLoad={this.showImage} style={ this.state.loaded ? {} : {display: "none"}} />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

**Edit:** As opposed to the other answers, the reason we want to do this is that replacing the src on an image is actually bad practice. If you want to roll an image it is better to have two `<img>` elements and toggle between them depending on conditions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What is the purpose or rather the meaning of this.state.loaded?

Comment: onLoad on an image element is called when the image has finished loading into the dom, this.state.loaded is a flag that we can set to true when the image has finished loading so you know that when you toggle off display:none it will show instantly.

Comment: a better name would probably be imageLoaded

Comment: So this refers to the component, wich containes the images?

Comment: Correct, all this component does is show one image while waiting for the other to load into the dom, when the other is loaded it will show the second image.

Comment: I see... Thank you!

Comment: I give the bounty in an hour when it lets me.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand the situation, you want to load the first image with the page then after the page has loaded, replace the first image with an image from another source.

In the example below the default image is "https://via.placeholder.com/100", it is displayed as the page loads. The second image is "https://via.placeholder.com/300", and is displayed after page load is complete.

Set up all image tags by adding the attribute **data-src="secondimage.jpg"** in the image tag.

**How this works**: After page load is complete, the script loops over all img tags checking for the data-src attribute. If an img tag has a data-src attribute it replaces the src image with the address in data-src attribute.

If you want to pre-load the external secondary images just add **new Image().src = "secondimage.jpg";** to your script.

If you press **Run code snippet** you will see the image shows 300 indicating the second image has replaced the first default one. See the commented section below for pre-loading secondary images if desired.

```js
/*
uncomment if you want to pre-load the secondary images
new Image().src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/300';
new Image().src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/400';
new Image().src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/500';
... as many as necessary
*/

window.onload = function() {
 imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');
 for (i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
  if (imgs[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
   imgs[i].setAttribute('src', imgs[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<img data-src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100">
```

Comment: Does this mean, that when it replaces the img's src it will only overwrite when it loads the second src of the imag fully?  So I'll get rid of the few second blank space?

Comment: I tested it just now online with a large data-src image and I did not get any blank time between the two images displaying.  The first image displayed for a fraction of a second then the second larger image replaced it immediately without blank space. I tested it with Chrome. If a different browser gives a blank space while the second image loads you could try pre-loading it by adding new Image().src = "url-of-second-image.jpg"; to your script, like the commented section above shows. But try it first without the pre-load because it didn't show any blank space for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can just update directly the src of the image, I have a sample on [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-shamir-dgxxf).

This is the content:

```
function App() {
  const [imageSrc, setImageSrc] = React.useState("/placeholder.jpg");

  function loadImage() {
    setImageSrc(`https://picsum.photos/200?${Date.now()}`);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <img alt="small-image" src={imageSrc} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={loadImage}>Load Image!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is just a basic example, you can implement your own logic. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you! But how do I adjust the src change to when the picture does load?

Comment: You mean, the src was already changed, but the image content is still loading, you want to have a fallback image?

Comment: What I mean is that when the page loads it has an img and it uses it to fill up images with content. I want that when the real images have loaded thy overwrite the default.

Comment: If I was not using a default image I would have a few (depending on the interconnection) seconds when the page is empty. This is what I want to avoid.

Comment: You could not achieve that by using image on initial load, as you can see, when the page loads, it fetches the assets and even though you have a default image it still need to be loaded. What you can do is maybe implement some Skeleton, example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loading-skeleton. By using this feature, you can combine it with https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image as your loader.

Comment: Can you explain what is this? :)

Comment: Check the link, I have given some examples: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-shamir-dgxxf