# How to preload largest-contentful-paint image in react helmet

Tags: reactjs, webpack, preload, lighthouse, react-helmet

I received this warning in lighthouse

[image]

I tried doing what that learn more link told me to do, and include a preload tag in the head for the image, but I still get the warning

---

I tried this preload tag, the url is the one which is in the browser when I right click the image and select "open in new tab"

```
<link rel="preload" as="image" href={`https://example.com:8080/src/assets/images/example.webp`} />
```

The image is just imported into the jsx component like `import banner from "images/banner-large.png";` and then rendered with an image tag like       `<img src={example} className="w-100 banner-img" alt="Description" />`

---

I'm also using `img-optimizer-loader`to web-optimize my images and convert them to webp in my webpack config like below

```
{
    test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|webm|webp)$/i,
    use: [
      {
        loader: "img-optimize-loader",

        options: {
          compress: {
            // This will transform your png/jpg into webp.
            webp: {
              quality: 75,
            },
            disableOnDevelopment: true,
          },
          name: "[path][name].[ext]",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
```

---

It's worth noting that I import my images like

```
import image from 'src/assets/images/example.png'
```

but because of `img-optimize-loader`, all my images are converted to webp in the build, and the webp images are the ones displayed.

Comment: Usually, I won't preload an image. Instead, I will display a blurry placeholder (which the resolution is super low like 20x80, and the file size is small enough to be embedded in the HTML file), then pre-fetch the actual image. Once the image is ready, replace the placeholder with the actual image, or render on top of it.

Comment: `disableOnDevelopment: true` - does that not stop the image being converted or have you set it to production? Have you checked that the request is for a `.webp` image and not the original `.png`?

Comment: @GrahamRitchie For some reason when i open the image in a new tab in development it's a webp

Comment: @MatthewKwong There's some other places that I want to do this. Do you have a link to an example

Comment: I'm not sure which toolchain you are using. If you are using Gatsby, there is a plugin you can use. If you are using CRA, then you have to implement it yourself

Comment: @MatthewKwong Not using Gatsby, just react and webpack

Comment: You may take a look at this for reference. https://jmperezperez.com/medium-image-progressive-loading-placeholder/

Answer (score 0):

Import and use `Helmet` right inside your image component:

```js
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet'
import example from "images/example.png";


function Image () {
  return (
    <Helmet>
      <link rel="preload" as="image" href={example}>
    </Helmet>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't fix the issue unfortunately, I noticed that I didn't specify this before, so I added an edit saying explaining how I import pngs or jpegs, but a plugin converts them to webp

Comment: what if you use dynamic import for the image and then preload it with [`webpackPreload`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#prefetchingpreloading-modules)? e.g. `import(/* webpackPreload: true */ './path/to/image.png');`

Answer (score 0):

It is not a front-end issue but rather a back-end one. In this case, react-helmet won't be of any help.
Here is an article that explain how to deal with dynamic meta tags to a React app without SSR.
https://blog.logrocket.com/adding-dynamic-meta-tags-react-app-without-ssr/

I also recommend reading this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/62853922/9580264