# ReactJS - Img(image) flickering when component rendered at first time

Tags: reactjs, image, jsx, flicker

When Reactjs Components are rendered at **first time**, imgs flicker.

How can I fix it?

```
<Example Code>

import AccountProfile from '../../img/AccountProfile.png';
...

return(
   <div className='MyAccount'>
      <img className='MyAccount_Img' src={AccountProfile}/> // <- img flicker when first rendered.
   </div>
);
```

P.S
Edit: [How to preload images in React.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42615556/how-to-preload-images-in-react-js)
I found the solution in here.

Comment: flicker mean the image comes up and goes and comes back? how many times? did you check the network requests to see what is going on?

Comment: @AkberIqbal Thanks for your helping. I check network requests, and the network sends requests to get images. This makes images flickering. Also, I found that I can preload images before the images are actually used. However, I checked that the network still sends requests again to get the preloaded images. I struggle with this problem.

Comment: @AkberIqbal I found the solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42615556/how-to-preload-images-in-react-js